# div position in Internet explorer

Tags: jquery, css, html, css-position

i having problems with the new slider that im making.

i have 3 div 1 relative and 2 absolute

the csss:
`#caixa_grande{ position:relative; width:150px; height:80px; overflow:hidden;}`
 `#texto{ position:absolute;}`
`.caixa_pequena{ position:absolute;}`

the jquery that is going to add the left side to the slider items

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    esq = 0;
$(".caixa_pequena").each(function(){
    var $element = $(this).css('left'); 
    final = parseFloat($element) + parseFloat(esq);        
    $(this).css('left', parseFloat(final) + 'px');
    esq = esq  + 200;   
});
});

function nav_depois(){
    $("#texto").animate({left: '-=200'}, 1500);
}

function nav_antes(){
   $("#texto").animate({left: '+=200'}, 1500);
}
```

and the divs

```
<div id="caixa_grande">
<div id="texto">    
    <div class="caixa_pequena">SPORT LISBOA E BENFICA</div>
    <div class="caixa_pequena">SPORTING CLUBE DE PORTUGAL</div>
    <div class="caixa_pequena">FUTEBOL CLUBE DOS COXOS</div>
</div>  
</div>
<div>
    <span><a id="nav_antes" onclick='nav_antes()'>nav_antes</a></span>
    <span><a id="nav_depois" onclick='nav_depois()'>nav_depois</a></span>
</div>
```

the problem is that in firefox the slider works fine and the div info is separated with the 200px but in the  internet explorer the slider works the info is all in the same position like absolute width no left.

here is the link;

[the page example](http://estorileden.4emotions.net/teste_slide.php)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: absolute` from `.caixa_pequena` class because `#texto` is already absolutely positioned.

Comment: found it. it wasnt the about the position but the left. in the `.caixa_pequena` i had to add the left attribute. like `left:0px`